# Angular 2 lazy loading - inputs/outputs

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular2-routing

I am trying to pass inputs/outputs to the lazy loaded component, but I'm not sure
how I can do that.

If it's not lazy loaded, I know that I can do that like this.

**test.ts**

```
testdata: string;

ngOnInit(){
  this.testdata = "TEST";
}
```

**test.html**

```
<test-component [data]="testdata"></test-component>
```

**testcomponent.ts**

```
@Input() data: string;
```

But what if *testcomponent* is lazy loaded and I have something like this?

*testcomponent* is loaded, when user goes on specific path.

**test.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Thank you guys. Its a shame, i completely missed that i can use services.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the following:

1. use a query string to pass the data to lazy loaded components; or
2. use a shared service to pass the data from main component and store the data in a variable and when the lazy component is loaded just read the value of this variable in `onInit` function

Comment: Why do lazy-loaded components do not pass data to `@Input()` variables?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use binding with components added by the router or `ViewContainerRef.createComponent`.

Use a shared service to communicate with components that are not direct parent-child like explained in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html